# How to set up a PHP Curl POST request which can trigger via a JavaScript onclick event?

Tags: javascript, php, curl, integration, activecampaign

I want to track the submit button click event at the form in javascript and send the submit button click event to curl PHP side and the url (https://trackcmp.net/event) in curl php file will send the event that I trigger and stored into the database(ActiveCampaign).

The form was created by ActiveCampaign and embedded into the Wordpress website.

Below are 2 files that I make, the 1st part is ajax file, and then 2nd part is PHP file.

May anyone help me please? Thank you.

```js
(function($){
$("_form_44__submit").on('click', function () {
    // fire the AJAX request on button click
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'curl.php',
       dataType: 'json',
       headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",},
       data: {actid: "actid",
    key: "key",
    event: "Click_Submit_Button_Event",
    visit: ["email"]
 },
    })
    .done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
       // if you want to do something on success
    })
    .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('error');
       // if you want to do something on error
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<?php


$actid = $_POST['actid'];
$key =  $_POST['key'];
$event =  $_POST['event'];
$visit =  $_POST['visit'];

$url = "https://trackcmp.net/event";

    $curl = curl_init(); //open connection /
    // changes the cURL session behavior with options POST
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'actid' => $actid,
        'key' => $key,
        'event' => $event,
        'visit' => $visit,
));
    //execute
    $result = curl_exec($curl); //handle $curl_init
    if ($result !== false) {
        $result = json_decode($result);
        if ($result->success) {
            echo 'Success! ';
        } else {
            echo 'Error! ';
        }

        echo $result->message;
    } else {
        echo 'cURL failed to run: ', curl_error($curl);
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the PHP curl works for you and that you have the data to populate the values in the ajax post so:

for the data to arrive to post PHP as $_POST you need to send it like this for example the $.ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "curl.php",
    data: "actid=actid&key=somekey&event=Click_Submit_Button_Event&visit=email@at.com",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Submission was successful.');
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('An error occurred.');
        console.log(data);
    },
});
```

Look at the way the data: is built... you can ofcourse do : `"actid="+actid+"&key="+key+ ... etc`

This way your PHP file will be able to read the form data.

If you'll print your $_POST it will look something like:

```
Array
(
    [actid] => actid
    [key] => somekey
    [event] => Click_Submit_Button_Event
    [visit] => email@at.com
)
```

***Edit*** here is a complete version with a form click and inputs :

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="contactForm1" action="curl.php" method="post">
            Actid <input type="text" name="actid" /><br>
            Key <input type="text" name="key" /><br>
            Event <input type="text" name="event" /><br>
            Visit <input type="text" name="visit" /><br>
            <input type="submit" />
            <!-- Form input fields here (do not forget your name attributes). -->
        </form>
    </body>
</html>



<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#contactForm1');

    frm.submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(frm.serialize()); /*show the data being sent from the form*/
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Submission was successful.');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('An error occurred.');
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

**for you PHP** I think you are mistaken with the array sending data ... you should try something like this: curl.php:
the post data will become a json which I suspect is what you need to send to your endpoint... it will look something like this:

{"actid":"actid","key":"key","event":"Click_Submit_Button_Event","visit":"someEmail@at.com"}

```
<?php
$post = json_encode($_POST);
print_r($post);

$url = "https://trackcmp.net/event";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Hi, I would very much appreciate your suggestion. Your suggestion is very nice. But I have some questions related to my question that I asked. Actually, the form that I used was embedded in the **Wordpress website**. And the **form class is "_form_44"**. Hence, may I request your suggestions on how to trigger the form that is embedded inside the Wordpress? Thank you.

Comment: Are you reaching the PHP file when the form is posted? In what stage you are stuck in the process?

Comment: It's work for the complete version with a form click and input part. But actually, the form has already been created and it is implemented inside the Wordpress website. But I don't know how to use an ajax call to trigger the form inside Wordpress. And send the tracked event (submit) when the person clicks to the url inside the php file (https://trackcmp.net/event). Any solution from you? Thank you.